# How to get available space on a network drive in c++?

Tags: c++, diskspace

I tried using `std::filesystem::space(dir)` but with no luck -> it cannot determine available disk space, sets it to uintmax.

```
auto info = std::filesystem::space("K:\\Dir");
if(info.available == static_cast<uintmax_t>(-1))
{
     std::cout << "Error occurred!\n";
}
```

`K:\Dir` does indeed exist. And this snippet prints `Error occurred` for my  drive mounted on `K:`.

Comment: You should show a [mcve] of what you have tried, which would include how you tried to get the free space from the result you get from the `std::filesystem::space` call. And it might be important to also mention which OS you tried your code on and how you mounted the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the free space you need to try

```
const std::filesystem::space_info spaceInfo = std::filesystem::space(dir);
cout << static_cast<std::intmax_t>(spaceInfo.free) << endl;
```

Here `dir = "/path/to/dir/"`;

Refer [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/space)

Comment: @InQusitive-> Please see my edited question.